# Calculating the number of sample error fall within certain range of average error

Tags: java, neural-network

Ok i don't really know how phrase this question but basically I am trying to determine how much of my sample data's error fall within a certain percentage range of the average error let say -5% to 5%.

Heres my code

```
  public void ErrorAnaysis(ArrayList<Marks> Set)
    {
        double sse = 0;
        double AvgError;
        double total=0;
        int count = 0;

        for(Marks mark: Set)
        {
            total+= Math.abs(mark.marks[3] - neuron.FnetLinear(mark.marks[0], mark.marks[1], mark.marks[2]));
            sse += Math.pow((mark.marks[3] - neuron.FnetLinear(mark.marks[0], mark.marks[1], mark.marks[2])),2);
            count++;
        }
        AvgError = total/count;

        System.out.println("Average error: " + AvgError + "\n SSE: " + sse + "\n");

        for(Marks mark: Set)
        {
            ///????
        }

    }
```

I am using a neuron to predict a mark based of 3 other marks and then subtracting it from the actual mark to get the error and then calculate the average of these errors.
What I want to do next is determine how many of these errors fall within a certain percentage range of my average error. How would I go about calculating this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want checking whether the accuracy/precision within a range around `avg` as:

```
Math.abs(avg - aDouble) < 0.05
```

should make sure the `aDouble` will be -5% and 5% around `avg` and complete local test will be:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    double avg = 0.90;
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(0.8503);
    list.add(0.89);
    list.add(0.90);
    list.add(0.9488);

    list.add(0.8309); // this will fail;
    list.add(0.849999); // this will fail;
    list.add(0.95001); // this will fail;

    int inRangeRate = 0;
    for (Double aDouble : list) {
        if (Math.abs(avg - aDouble) < 0.05) {
            inRangeRate++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("In Range Count: " + inRangeRate);
}
```

it will give you:

```
In Range Count: 4
```